# Duplicate variable in pattern for tuples

Tags: tuples, sml

I'm learning pattern matching in SML and I want to write a function `fact_till (a,b)` to calculate a!/b!. So for example, fact_till(5,3) should return 5*4=20.

My code looks like this:

```
fun fact_till t = case t of
                  (a,a) => 1
                | (a,b) => a * fact_till(a-1,b)
```

But I got `Error: duplicate variable in pattern(s): a`. I presume SML does not recognize the pattern `(a,a)`. Then what's the correct way of expressing this pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is:

```
fun fact_till (a,b) = if a = b
                      then 1
                      else a * fact_till(a - 1, b)
```

This can also be done with a case statement, if you wish:

```
fun fact_till (a,b) = case a = b of
                      true => 1
                    | false => a * fact_till(a - 1, b)
```

Comment: Not so fancy, though :(